# book about a girl who moves to California and starts dating a ghost

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

I'm trying to identify a book about a girl who moved to California and discovered a ghost in her room. She started dating him, and brought him to life. His name Was Jesse, I think. I also remember something about an exorcist or something similar.

Comment: You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be the Meg Cabot novel, *[Shadowland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowland_(Cabot_novel))* (titled *[Love You to Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21494230-love-you-to-death)* in the UK apparently)?

> Sixteen-year-old Susannah 'Suze' Simon is a mediator, which means she can see and talk to ghosts. Suze spends a lot of time directing the usually unhappy dead to the afterlife. However, her job is not easy, as not all ghosts want to be guided. Every day, she is haunted by the fact that they will not leave her alone until she helps them resolve their unfinished business with the living.
>
> Suze, whose father died when she was six, moves from New York to Carmel, California after her mom's second marriage to Andy Ackerman, a carpenter. She gets three stepbrothers, Jake, Brad, and David, whom she nicknames Sleepy (a senior), Dopey (a sophomore like Suze), and Doc (a seventh grader). However, when Suze arrives at her new home, she finds a handsome, archaic ghost named Jesse de Silva sitting on her window seat. Irritated, she tells Jesse to move on or find some other house to haunt, as now she is living there, but he refuses.

....

> Several days later, Heather attempts to kill Bryce again, and is barely stopped by Father Dominic; both men are injured in the process. Furious, Suze returns to school that evening - ignoring Jesse's warnings - and performs a voodoo exorcism, successfully sending Heather to the afterlife. However, as she is exorcised, Heather causes the school breezeway to collapse on Suze, who is knocked unconscious and barely saved by Sleepy and Doc.

FWIW, my search terms were *novel girl california ghost jesse* although I first had to scroll past descriptions and reviews of *Jesse's Ghost*.

Comment: You guys nailed it once again, thank so much.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this could be *[The Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mediator)*, a series by [Meg Cabot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meg_Cabot).

From Wikipedia:

> The series follows along with a girl named Susannah "Suze" Simon and her experiences as a teenage mediator - a person who has abilities to see, touch and talk to ghosts... Suze's problem is that she was in love with a nineteenth-century ghost known as Hector de Silva, or what she calls him, Jesse.

And, on the Wikipedia entry for the [first book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowland_(Cabot_novel)):

> Suze, whose father died when she was six, moves from New York to Carmel, California after her mom's second marriage to Andy Ackerman, a carpenter.

Comment: Och... jinx! :-D